# U2 Universe ODBC Access

Tags: odbc, universe, u2

Hello I'm trying to connect to a Universe DB with ODBC.
I have successfully imported some data into access for most of the tables. 
(I'm using access just to look at the data and get a general idea of everything)

There are a few tables that will not import due to precision errors.

I'm just starting out with this database type so I'm fairly new to all this. Although I do have past AS/400 (DB2) experience back in the day. The dictionary files remind me of that a bit.

Anyways the problem is a with a field with amounts in it. It works fine unless the amount is greater then 999.99 then I get an error about the field being too small. Apparently ODBC is assuming the field is precision of 5 with 2 decimal places. I looked at the dictionary file and  as far as I can tell the field is set to 10R  with a conversion code of MR2 which seems like it should be adequate.

Where do I set this in Universe so that ODBC knows it is larger then that.

Thanks for any help.

Update::: I was looking at wrong field the output format of the field I need in the dictionary is actually 7R. If that makes any difference.

Comment: Just for reference, what are the full 10 attributes of your dictionary entry?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by Full 10 Attributes.. But if this is what you mean :  FieldName = I.PAY | Type and Field Number = A  0 | Field Definition = F;0;(G1:1) | Conversion Code = MR2 | Column heading = Item Payment | Output Format = 7R | Depth & Assoc = M

Comment: What are you using to edit dictionary entries?

Comment: I was using TCL within the SB2 client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting attribute 6 in your dictionary entry to DECIMAL then run HS.UPDATE.FILEINFO at TCL:

```
>ED DICT MYFILE I.PAY
10 lines long.

----: 6
0006:
----: R DECIMAL
0006: DECIMAL
----: FI
```

Check out [Rocket's ODBC documentation](http://www.adbk.se/manuals/uv10/uvdoc/UniVerse/uvodbc.pdf) (page 75-76) for how to optionally set custom precision and scale in the dictionary entry for the DECIMAL SQL Data Type.

Comment: That gives me an error about MR2 conversion not working on an Integer type. I found a document finally that lays out the dictionary file attributes that seems to be helpful. I'm worried removing the conversion code will mess with the program that is using the database?

Comment: I think Basically webthaumaturge is pointing me in the right direction. I'm wary of changing to much because I'm not 100% familar how the software system is accessing these files so I'm afraid a change will break something.  They offer a web based reporting tool that seems to work. Although it is a bit clunky. So I will attempt to use that. But I think If I added the SQL type and removed the conversion code it would work.

Comment: @user2956601, you can copy the dictionary item to a new name and change that one instead if you are worried about breaking existing code.

Comment: Note that the answer supplied by webthaumaturge is referring to A and S descriptors. For D and I descriptors, attribute 6 defines Single or Multivalue while attribute 8 is the SQL datatype.